# remove string between "|" and "," in stringbuilder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, stringbuilder

I use VS2019 in Windows7.
I want to remove string between `"|"` and `","` in a `StringBuilder`.

That is , I want to convert `StringBuilder` from

```
"578.552|0,37.986|317,38.451|356,23"
```

to

```
"578.552,37.986,38.451,23"
```

I have tried `Substring` but failed, what other method I could use to achieve this?

Comment: you can use my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62468221/6527049

Comment: What about [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: is it necessary to use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string`? I mean, the stirng is not very long, so you would have a performance gain if you need to process several million of those strings in a second.

Comment: @viveknuna that doesn't help with `StringBuilder`

Comment: @imsmn that doesn't help with `StringBuilder`

Comment: @MarcGravell but he can use the similar logic

Comment: `myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(Regex.Replace(myStringBuilder.ToString(), @"\|.*?\,", ","));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` isn't really setup for much by way of inspection and mutation *in the middle*. It would be pretty easy to do once you have a `string` (probably via a `Regex`), but `StringBuilder`? not so much. In reality, `StringBuilder` is *mostly* intended for forwards-only append, so the answer would be:

> if you didn't want those characters, *why did you add them?*

Maybe just use the `string` version here; then:

```cs
var s = "578.552|0,37.986|317,38.451|356,23";
var t = Regex.Replace(s, @"\|.*?(?=,)", ""); // 578.552,37.986,38.451,23
```

The regex translation here is "pipe (`\|`), non-greedy anything (`.*?`), followed by a comma where the following comma isn't part of the match (`(?=,)`).

Comment: While this is true the OP _might_ use `StringBuilder.Chars` to search for the range of text to delete and then `StringBuilder.Remove()` it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what is `StringBuilder.Chars`? do you mean the indexer?

Comment: Yes (_padding for min comment length_)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `StringBuilder.Remove` is *not* an efficient way of working with it - it is wrong to assume "I'm using `StringBuilder`, therefore mutation is cheap" - only *append* is cheap(ish)

Comment: This answer correctly states that string builders are forward-looking **builders** not string editors. StringBuilder ain't the tool for this job.

Comment: An in-place `Array.Copy()` (assumption about how `String.Remove()` might be implemented) is still WAY faster than creating a new string (for big enough strings where you might care about it)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti do you know what is even faster? not adding data you don't want :) and it isn't a simple copy - `StringBuilder` uses a chained chunk layout internally, so `Remove` is a lot more complex than you might think

Comment: I'm not saying it's _cheap_; I'm saying it's very possibly _cheaper_ than creating the `string` and applying a regex replace (with the assumption that it won't create even more temporary strings and it's the _newish_ Core 3 implementation). That should hold even if you call `ToString()` immediately after this (again, if the string is big _enough_).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **huge** `StringBuilder` and that's why converting it into `String` and applying regular expression is not the option,
you can try implementing Finite State Machine (FSM):

```
  StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder("578.552|0,37.986|317,38.451|356,23");

  int state = 0; // 0 - keep character, 1 - discard character
  int index = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i) {
    char c = source[i];

    if (state == 0) 
      if (c == '|')
        state = 1;
      else
        source[index++] = c;
    else if (c == ',') {
      state = 0;
      source[index++] = c;
    }
  }

  source.Length = index;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know very much of Regex patterns, you can write your own custom method to filter out data; its always instructive and a good practicing exercise:

```
public static String RemoveDelimitedSubstrings(
    this StringBuilder s,
    char startDelimitter,
    char endDelimitter,
    char newDelimitter)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    var ignore = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        var currentChar = s[i];

        if (currentChar == startDelimitter && !ignore)
        {
            ignore = true;
        }
        else if (currentChar == endDelimitter && ignore)
        {
            ignore = false;
            buffer.Append(newDelimitter);
        }
        else if (!ignore)
            buffer.Append(currentChar);

    }

    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

And youd obvisouly use it like:

```
var buffer= new StringBuilder("578.552|0,37.986|317,38.451|356,23");
var filteredBuffer = b.RemoveDelimitedSubstrings('|', ',', ','));
```